# Python socket to send rows of data

Tags: python, sockets

Greetings and apologies in advance if it looks a real novice question. I am new to python, or programming for that matter. I am writing a code that sends data from client to server. The data I need to send is from an csv file, which has around 10,000 rows. Currently I am sending the data in a large buffer as a whole, but I would prefer to send it row by row and also receive it the same way. I am not sure if I should use the split() function or there are any better ways to do the same thing.

The client...

```
import socket

HOST = 'server IP'        
PORT = 42050              
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
f = open('csvfile.csv', 'rb')
l = f.read(409600)
while True:
    print l    
    s.send(l)    
    break
f.close()
print "Done Sending"
s.close()
```

The server...

```
import socket

HOST = 'local IP'      
PORT = 42050              
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
print "Server running", HOST, PORT
s.listen(5)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print'Connected by', addr
while True:
    data = conn.recv(409600)          
    print repr(data)
    if not data: break
print "Done Receiving"
conn.close()
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

im not sure what your question actually is ... but its pretty easy to send and receive lines

```
#client.py
for line in open("my.csv"):
    s.send(line)


#server.py
def read_line(sock):
    return "".join(iter(lambda:sock.recv(1),"\n"))
```

`iter(lambda:sock.recv(1),"\n")`

is essentially the same as

```
result = ""
while not result.endswith("\n"): result += sock.recv(1)
```

Comment: Thanks!! Now that you explained it looks simple enough.

Comment: In def read_line(sock) where does "sock" come from? How does this method look incorporated into OPs server.py code exactly?